Difference in DOS and Transmission in the ballistic regime
Regarding the calculation of the transmission function, I understand that this is related to the number of modes * the transmission probability, and in the case of ballistic calculations the transmission probability should equal to one.
This should make the transmission function exactly equal to the number of modes. This would mean that I could extract the transmission function, without considering the NEGF, by counting the number of bands per k-point (and then sum all of them to have the transmission of the system).
However, isn't this the same way one calculates the DOS? What is the difference between the calculations of the two, in the case of a fully pristine (electrodes and central region made of the same material) system?
